# Linked List of BST in C: Breadth First Search

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I am writing a program that is a linked list of binary search trees.  We are supposed to search for a number in the trees and print the tree and line number found.  Because of this, we are supposed to use a Breadth-First Search function.  I am getting a segmentation fault in my dequeue function and I am unsure why.

These are my structures:

```
typedef struct BST {
    int value;
    int treeNum;
    struct BST* left;
    struct BST* right;
}BST;

typedef struct rootList{
    struct BST* root;
    struct rootList* next;
}rootList;

typedef struct bfsQ{
    struct BST* treeNode;
    struct bfsQ* next;
}bfsQ;
```

This is my BFS function:

```
void BFS(rootList* listHead, int searchValue)
{
    if(listHead->root == NULL)
    {
        printf("%d/tNO/tN/A/tN/A\n", searchValue);
    }
    else
    {
        bfsQ* newQueue = NULL;
        BST* temp = NULL;

        newQueue = malloc(sizeof(bfsQ));
        newQueue->next = NULL;
        enqueue(&newQueue, listHead->root);
        while(newQueue != NULL)
        {
            temp = dequeue(&newQueue);
            printf("Did this work?");
            if(temp->value == searchValue)
                printf("HI I WAS FOUND");
            else
            {
                if(temp->left != NULL)
                    enqueue(&newQueue, temp->left);
                if(temp->right != NULL)
                    enqueue(&newQueue, temp->right);
            }
        }
        BFS(listHead->next, searchValue);
    }
}
```

This is my enqueue:

```
void enqueue(bfsQ** qHead, BST* new_tree_node)
{
    bfsQ *temp = malloc(sizeof(bfsQ));
    BST *node;
    temp->treeNode = new_tree_node;
    temp->next = *qHead;
    *qHead = temp;
    node = temp->treeNode;
    printf("%d\n", node->value);
}
```

This is my dequeue:

```
BST* dequeue(bfsQ** qHead)
{
    bfsQ *temp, *first;
    BST *newBST;
    temp = (*qHead);
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("THIS IS NOT NULL YET\n");
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    first = temp;
    newBST = first->treeNode;
    free(temp);
    return first->treeNode;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The enqueue is working correctly, however my dequeue is not storing correctly.

EDIT: Apparently I need to:

"This function implements a variant of a level by level search or formally
    called as the BREADTH FIRST SEARCH.
 -> This function searches for a given value in the binary trees and it does that
    by searching for level 1 in each binary trees, then moving on to level 2 if
    it fails to find it that value in level 1 and so on.
 -> Basically, you have to search for a given value in all the binary trees, one
    level at a time, in the linked list simultaneously."

So I'm not sure if I need to search the whole tree, then move on, or look at each tree, line by line.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

From the superficial look I had into the code, it looks generally ok (though I would have implemented some parts differently), but the last lines in `dequeue()` are certainly wrong:

```
first = temp;
newBST = first->treeNode;
free(temp);
return first->treeNode;
```

Accessing `first->treeNode` in the last line is catastrophic: `first` holds an address that has already been freed (`temp` and `first` refer to the same memory location). I think you wanted to return `newBST` instead:

```
return newBST;
```

You might as well throw `first` away, as it seems useless, and turn that into:

```
newBST = temp->treeNode;
free(temp);
return newBST;
```